# equals() method of objects is acting different with String objects and the Objects I created?

Tags: java, string, oop, methods, equals

I am confused with .equals() method for objects in the case 2 and case 3. For the case 1, I can understand that references and the contents are the same, so we got the true, true respectively.

In the case 2, equals() method compares the type and content, and returns true (according to documentation, it first compare the object type and then compares the content). However in the 3rd case, even if the types and contents are the same, it returns False! ?
Is there any special feature of the String object? Any help/ hint/ explanation is appreciated.

```
public class equalMethods {

static class MyObject {

       String name;

    // constructor
    MyObject(String s) {
        this.name = s;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // ***CASE 1****
    String a = "str1"; 
    String b = "str1";
    System.out.println(a == b); // True
    System.out.println(a.equals(b));// True
    System.out.println();

    // ***CASE 2****
    String an = new String("oracle");
    String bn = new String("oracle");
    System.out.println(an == bn); // False
    System.out.println(an.equals(bn));// True ( ? Compare with case 3)
    System.out.println();

    // // ***CASE 3****
    MyObject object1 = new MyObject("str1");
    MyObject object2 = new MyObject("str1");
    System.out.println(object1 == object2); // False
    System.out.println(object1.equals(object2)); // False ( ? Compare with case 2) 
    System.out.println();

}

}
```

Comment: Java already has an Object class. Probably should call your class something else.

Comment: I know, I changed it, still same result, but i got the answers below. thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general behavior is, `equals()` is inherited from `Object` class into all the java class with its default implementation. All the classes should provide the equality as required for their objects. So if you are writing any custom class (usually POJO) which uses collection framework or uses instance equality, then you should implement the `equals()` method on the respective instance members.

```
Object object1 = new Object("sam");
Object object2 = new Object("sam");
System.out.println(object1 == object2); // False
System.out.println(object1.equals(object2)); // False ( ? Compare with case 2)
```

Because here it is calling the `equals()` method from the `Object` class. Which check the reference equality only. Both the objects are different and so `false`.

---

```
String an = new String("oracle");
String bn = new String("oracle");
System.out.println(an == bn); // False
System.out.println(an.equals(bn));// True ( ? Compare with case 3)
```

Here the `equals()` implementation from `String` class is invoked, which checks for reference equality and content equality as well so it matches and returns `true`.

---

If you are overriding the behavior of `equals()` for any class, it is recommended to override `hashCode()` method as well.

Answer (score 3):

You want to add something like this in the MyObject def:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof MyObject)) return false;
    if (obj == this) return true;
    MyObject that = (MyObject)obj;

    return this.name.equals(that.name);
}
```

otherwise you will get the `equals()` method from java's Object class, which is not very useful to you.  The String class defines an `equals()` method.

And once you give a mouse an `equals()`, he's going to want a `hashCode()`...

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.name.hashCode();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation! I got it.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice for a custom class is to overwrite the default equals method.  String have an equals method.  You need to write one for your Object class.  The default is comparing references in memory, not the content of the Strings.

Comment: And when overriding `equals`, always override `hashCode`, and vice versa.